# invalid command name ".!canvas"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm attempting to create a canvas with 100 completely random rectangles appearing, but what I get is a blank canvas and an error:

invalid command name ".!canvas"

How do i fix this?

```
from tkinter import *
import random
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
tk.mainloop()

def rndm_rect(width, height):
    x1 = (random.randrange(width))
    y1 = (random.randrange(height))
    x2 = x1 + (random.randrange(width))
    y2 = y1 + (random.randrange(width))
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)

rndm_rect(400, 400)


for x in range(0, 100):
    rndm_rect(400, 400)
```

Comment: I would also recommend updating your title to an actual question

Comment: It is because tkinter window closed but other processes related to it e.g. `canvas.delete('ball')` is still running. To avoid this, put **try** and **except** when calling `animate()` function. To avoid the error, `import sys` and do this whenever `animate()` is called: `try: self.animate()` `except: sys.exit(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tk.mainloop()` is the command used to start the event loop, as such you're generating the window before you've declared the variables for the rectangle positions.

Place `tk.mainloop()` at the end of your script and it runs fine, see below:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

def rndm_rect(width, height):
    x1 = (random.randrange(width))
    y1 = (random.randrange(height))
    x2 = x1 + (random.randrange(width))
    y2 = y1 + (random.randrange(width))
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)

rndm_rect(400, 400)


for x in range(0, 100):
    rndm_rect(400, 400)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"tk.mainloop() is the command used to generate the tKinter master window"_ - that is a false statement. It doesn't create or generate any windows, it simply starts the event loop.