# _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas" error in turtle grahics

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to  create a polygon using turtle graphics but I keep on running to this error

> self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
> _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas

"

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
def polygon(t,length,n):
    angle = 360%n
    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(angle)

polygon(bob,70,7)
```

Comment: This error [usually happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68719923/python-turtle-game-error-tkinter-tclerror-invalid-command-name-canvas) when you try to run turtle commands after already having closed the window.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error, we may need to see more of it to understand the problem.  However, code-wise, I would have expected `/` (floating division) instead of `%` (modulus remainder):

```
import turtle

def polygon(t, length, n):
    angle = 360 / n

    for _ in range(n):
        t.forward(length)
        t.left(angle)

bob = turtle.Turtle()
polygon(bob, 70, 7)

turtle.done()
```

[image]