# How to make an object's clones follow the same function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have an object, let's call it 'ant', and I made it move, and every 10 second I make a clone of it,
but the clone doesn't follow the same function that the ant had.

Is there a way to make the clones follow the same function?
There will be about 10 or 20 more clones.

```py
import turtle
import random

#make a variable moves and create an object ant
moves = 0
ant = turtle.Turtle()

#I make the direction of the ant random
ant.setheading(random.randint(0, 360))

#create A definition that makes the ant move and creates a clone
def move():
    ant.forward(10)

    if moves == 10:
        ant.clone()

    else:
        moves += 1

move()
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this. If you want to know *how*, then you should share a [mre] of your code and share some examples of how you want this to work. Because you're just asking if it's _possible_ right now. You're making us have to extrapolate too much about how things should work.

Comment: I have added the code snippet

Comment: Thanks for adding some code. I suggest you edit it to a [mre] so that people can understand and resolve your problem.

Comment: the thing is There is not really any code that needs fixing.
I need to add code

Comment: "*the clone doesn't follow the same function that the ant had.*"—It sounds like you have some code that needs fixing.

Comment: Well all the 'important' part of my code is here

Comment: Great. Now make it a [mre].

Comment: So I hope that is what you mean

Comment: Thanks for adding code. Voted to reopen, although if you could [edit] to fix your indentation, that'd be fantastic. You probably want a list of turtles, loop over them and run the same code for each one.

Comment: `ant.clone()` RETURNS the cloned object.  You are simply throwing it away.  You would have to store it (in a list, maybe?), and if you want all the ants to move, you have to tell each of them to move.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your logic for one ant in a function, you can then use `Screen().ontimer(run_ant, 10_000)` to kick off a new ant every 10 seconds.

```py
from random import randint
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


def run_ant():
    ant = Turtle()
    ant.setheading(randint(0, 360))

    for _ in range(10):
        ant.forward(10)


def run_ants():
    Screen().ontimer(run_ant)

    if len(Screen().turtles()) < 10:
        Screen().ontimer(run_ant, 10_000)


run_ants()
Screen().exitonclick()
```

Note that these turtles are never garbage collected, so the app will slow down if you keep doing this. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73263441/6243352) for details.

You may also see strange errors like ([`_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68719923/python-turtle-game-error-tkinter-tclerror-invalid-command-name-canvas)) if the turtle screen closes while a turtle is in the midst of executing an operation in a different thread. I'm not sure if you even want to exit on click, so I won't dive into this--I'm using it as a convenience. Most animations use `tracer(0)` and `update()` to render each frame, which avoids the error (but the code gets a bit more complex and out of scope).