# Error when using screen.trace(0) in turtle: _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"

Tags: python, pycharm, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to create a snake game but I am stuck.

When I try using `screen.trace(0)`, my turtle graphic window is freezing and I got errors:

```
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

What's causing this and how can I fix the error?

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("Snake Game")
screen.tracer(0)

x_positions = [-20,0,20]
segments = []

for snake_index in range(0, 3):
    new_snake = Turtle(shape="square")
    new_snake.color("green")
    new_snake.penup()
    new_snake.goto(y=0, x=x_positions[snake_index])
    segments.append(new_snake)

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    for seg in segments:
        seg.forward(20)
        screen.update()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because there's no way out of your main `while` loop except to kill the window ungracefully, which can trigger this error. `screen.exitonclick()` is unreachable in your script.

`ontimer` should be preferred over the `while True: screen.update()` idiom, which has no clear framerate and basically runs as fast as the computer can handle. With `while True:`, you get wildly different performance on different machines. On my machine, the snake instantly flies off the screen, for example.

If you use `ontimer`, you can more carefully control the speed at which frames are drawn, and the callback-driven nature of the loop means your code can reach the `screen.exitonclick()` call before it begins the animation. This lets you actually exit on click and clean up nicely.

Here's an example:

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


def update():
    for seg in segments:
        seg.forward(20)

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(update, target_fps)


screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("Snake Game")
screen.tracer(0)

x_positions = [-20, 0, 20]
segments = []

for snake_index in range(0, 3):
    new_snake = Turtle(shape="square")
    new_snake.color("green")
    new_snake.penup()
    new_snake.goto(y=0, x=x_positions[snake_index])
    segments.append(new_snake)

target_fps = 1000 // 3  # roughly 3 frames per second
update()  # schedule the first frame
screen.exitonclick()  # start the turtle main loop and exit on click
```

Note that `update()` is only called once per frame, not once per segment. Think of `update()` as redrawing a single frame and `ontimer` as scheduling how much time should pass before the next frame is drawn.

It's not a perfect real-time approach, but it's better than `while True:`. Although turtle isn't designed for real-time applications, this should be good enough for most toy games like snake.

---

Related questions:

- [Python turtle game error _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68719923/python-turtle-game-error-tkinter-tclerror-invalid-command-name-canvas)
- [_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63179756/tkinter-tclerror-invalid-command-name-canvas)
- [tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65643645/tkinter-tclerror-invalid-command-name-canvas)
- [invalid command name ".!canvas"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508038/invalid-command-name-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your while loop never ends, so your `screen.exitonclick()` is never reached. The only way to end the code is to kill it. I suggest finding a place
to kill the while loop. I won't directly give you the code because I want you to find out how to do it.